# How can you manipulate db content thats returned from findAll function in model hook of ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, couchdb, pouchdb

The return value of findAll is an unknown mixin. eg . in router xyz.js

```
model(){
a = this.store.findAll('food-track');
return a
}
```

How do we manipulate a or extract data from a in model itself like

```
model(){
a = this.store.findAll('food-track');
some_data = a['_id'];
some_more_data = a['name'];
return some_more_data
}
```

But then a isn't in a format that I expected it to be in and I wasn't able to perform any function like this? Btw the data is taken from couch/pouchdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with kumkanillam answer: `findAll` will return an array so you'll have to iterate over it.

Also, depending on what your needs are, you can use computed properties to manipulate your model property as well. Here are the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc-toggle) from Ember

Comment: the link you provided had this code.

      fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
        return `${this.get('firstName')} ${this.get('lastName')}`;

Is there any reference to how this works?

 `${this.get('firstName')} ${this.get('lastName')}`;

Comment: In that particular example, the way `fullName` computed property works is that it observes the model's `firstName` and `lastName` property and returns a string with a space between the first and last name.

As for `${this.get('firstName')} ${this.get('lastName')}` this is the string that's being returned. Inorder to access the model properties `firstName` and `lastName` you must call the `.get()` method. The `this` refers to the current scope. In this example `this` refers to the current model.

Comment: docs on `.get()` and `.set()` methods. Its really useful: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#toc_using-code-get-code-and-code-set-code

Answer (score 1):

`findAll` returns `Promise` which will be resolved to `RecordArray` which extends [ArrayProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html) so you can use all the methods available in ArrayProxy.

```
model(){
 return this.store.findAll('food-track').then((result) => {
  //here you can forEach method to iterate and to filter use filterBy
  //Use objectAt(index) to retrieve object and use get and set 
  //dont forget to the return transformed result.
  return result;
});
}
```